# Background image reduces light from HDRI

Tags: modeling, light, lighting, hdri

I'm building an interior scen consisting of a room with four windows, see image below. Behind the four windows, on the outside I have a plane with a background image to get a nice view from the camera. The light in the scene comes from a Hdri image.

But I guess the plane prevent a lot of light to enter into the room because of the plane? Is there a way hide the plane for the Hdri light, but still be visible for the camera?

[image]

Comment: There is "Cycles settings" at the bottom of "Object tab". Uncheck everything except "Camera". Thus it will become visible only for camera

Comment: @SergeL Thanks for the answer! I have tried that and I didn't saw any difference, but I should check it again.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but try increasing the emission of your background plane.